# Sole problems with Slug and Date Field problem in Django

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-forms

I have a problem with Django code, I'm working with models to create an alternative post-creation page and the date wiget generated is a text-input. Also autocomplete not work for Slug. Someone can help me?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

# Categorie
class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    name = models.CharField('Titolo', max_length = 250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, unique = True)
    desc = models.TextField('Descrizione', max_length=10000, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Articles
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Titolo', max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    category = models.ForeignKey (Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    desc = models.CharField('Descrizione', max_length=10000, blank=True, )
    text = models.TextField('Testo', max_length=10000, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField('Foto', blank=True, upload_to="img")
    data = models.DateTimeField('Data di pubblicazione', blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, null = True, blank = True, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("admin", args=(str(self.id)))

    class Meta: # Order post by date
        ordering = ['-data',]
    def __str__(self):
        return "Ciao"
```

add_post.html:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Add - Post</h1>

    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button> Go</button>
    
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to override save method for automatic slug creation

```
from django.utils.text import slugify


class Category(models.Model):
...

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.brand_name)
    super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

this works when you create a model after you change date will not change

```
data = models.DateTimeField('Data di pubblicazione', auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

this date change every time when you create model and also update model

```
data = models.DateTimeField('Data di pubblicazione',auto_now=True blank=True)
```

Comment: this worked for slug (obv not for the date-field), thx you a lot

Comment: for date time field added in the answer